# String replacement in LaTeX

Tags: diagrams, lengths, strings

I'd like to know how to replace parts of a string in LaTeX. Specifically I'm given a measurement (like 3pt, 10mm, etc) and I'd like to remove the units of that measurement (so 3pt-->3, 10mm-->10, etc). The reason why I'd like a command to do this is in the following piece of code:

```
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\sbox{\mybox}{Hello World!}
\newlength{\myboxw}
\settowidth{\myboxw}{\usebox{\mybox}}
\begin{picture}(\myboxw,\myboxw)
\end{picture}
```

Basically I create a `savebox` called mybox. I insert the words "Hello World" into mybox. I create a new length, called myboxw. I then get the width of mybox, and store this in myboxw. Then I set up a square `picture` environment whose dimensions correspond to myboxw. The trouble is that myboxw is returning something of the form "132.56pt", while the input to the `picture` environment has to be dimensionless: `\begin{picture}{132.56, 132.56}`.

So, I need a command which will strip the units of measurement from a string.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The internal LaTeX macro `\strip@pt` returns a length in pt without the unit. For example, if you set `\myboxw` to 10 mm, it will have a length of 28.45274 pt, and this code

```
\makeatletter
\strip@pt\myboxw
\makeatother
```

will output just 28.45274. So you could use this or define your own command like:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\stripunit}[1]{\strip@pt#1}
\makeatother
```

`\strip@pt` uses `\the` on a dimen register and strips `pt`, that's why you did not get 10 (mm) but the corresponding value in pt without unit. Such a conversion to pt and stripping pt seems better to me than just doing string replacement getting some value without knowing the unit.

You can see the source code of `\strip@pt` with comment if you look into source2e.pdf in section *26.1 Macros for the user* (part of the section *26. Selecting a new font*), you could open it at the command prompt by typing `texdoc source2e` or get it from [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/source2e).

Comment: This is the right command to use under the circumstances. Being able to strip `mm` and other units (as specified in the question) isn't necessary in this case. (Which you'd probably do with string replacement instead of the technique here.)

Comment: From `source2e`: `\expandafter\endgroup\x` – that’s a mean, mean trick. But I wonder: why not just use `\gdef` inside the group instead of this indirect definition? Any technical reason?

Comment: Thanks a lot. The above solution seems to work, so I'll mark that as the accepted answer. I have another related question though, which you may or may not know the answer to... but when I use \stripunit{\myboxw} in a picture environment, if I prefix this with an integer, it treats the length as n times that length. If I prefix it without an integer, say 0.5\stripunit{\myboxw}, latex throws an error, complaining about units (which is confusing, because picture environment doesn't need them).

Comment: At least you could write `\setlength{\halfw}{.5\myboxw}` and `\stripunit{halfw}` afterwards. Further there are packages for calculation like `fp`.

Answer (score 5):

ConTeXt defines `\withoutpt` like this:

```
{\catcode`\.=\@@other
 \catcode`\p=\@@other
 \catcode`\t=\@@other
 \gdef\WITHOUTPT#1pt{#1}}

\def\withoutpt#1%
  {\expandafter\WITHOUTPT#1}
```

(syst-ext.mkii)

So you can use this or a similar mechanism to strip the "pt" suffix.

Comment: Is `\@@other` the same as `\other`?

Comment: I guess that both are the same. `\other` is a LaTeX chardef, right?

Comment: What's the point of making a period have catcode 12? And doesn't that require using `\withoutpt{\the\wd0}` or something?

Comment: Neither `\other` nor `\@@other` exist in standard LaTeX.

Comment: @TH: paranoia, I guess. In some environments, the dot can be active.

Comment: @Taco: It's not clear to me how that's an issue here. I can't figure out how not having it could break anything.

Comment: @Patrick, @Will: It's defined `\chardef\other = 12` in Eplain.  Somehow I got the idea that it's defined in Plain Tex, but it's not.

Answer (score 1):

The `picture` package allows you to use dimens in the arguments of `picture` commands, so a `\usepackage{picture}` should be enough to solve your problem.